# What is the fastest way to move in Darksiders?

Tags: darksiders

In Darksiders I feel like I run really slowly, and when I have to cross a decently long stretch of ground running in a straight line, it just takes a long time. Is there a combination of jumping/dashing/running that allows you to travel faster than just running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normal dashing is faster than running, but it is a bit clunky. (Dash, stop; dash, stop... etc).

However, there is a glitch you can exploit to speed things up more, by using an aerial sideways/backwards dash, then using Mercy (the gun) to cancel the dash.

However the fastest way to move, is by using Ruin, but he is only accessible after a certain point in the game (you find him in the Arena before fighting the Stygian), and he is only accessible in certain areas of the game as well (again, primarily the Ashlands).

Comment: It's a shame the dash animation doesn't transition into running smoothly. It would make it much nicer.